# Can't figure out error in lapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I am a beginner having picked up R a few weeks ago and am trying to learn the `apply` family. Can't figure out how to use `lapply` and it is maddenning. Yes, I looked up `?lapply` and several books including [R in a nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680170X) and [R cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596809158) and still can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

```
lapply(X = c("ggplot2", "gtable", "grid"), library)
## Error: 'package' must be of length 1
lapply(X = c("ggplot2", "gtable", "grid"), FUN = function(x) library(x))
## Error: there is no package called 'x'
lapply(X = c("ggplot2", "gtable", "grid"), FUN = library)
## Error: 'package' must be of length 1
x = c("ggplot2", "gtable", "grid")
lapply(x, library)
## Error: 'package' must be of length 1
lapply(x, FUN = function(x) library(x))
## Error: there is no package called 'x'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `lapply()` per se, but the problem is that `library()` evaluates its arguments in a slightly special way.

This means you need to use

```
library(pkg.name, character.only=TRUE)
```

This is rather obscure in the help for `?library`:

> package, help
>   the name of a package, given as a name or literal
>   character string, or a character string, depending on whether
>   character.only is FALSE (default) or TRUE).

What this means is that if you supply a character string to `library()`, you *must* set `character.only` to TRUE.

So, try this:

```
lapply(x, library, character.only=TRUE)
```

Then you will probably want to call `require()` instead of `library()`, and simplify the results with `sapply`:

```
sapply(x, require, character.only=TRUE)
ggplot2  gtable    grid 
   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
```

The difference is that `require()` returns a single logical value indicating whether the package was loaded successfully or not.

Comment: Some years later, the above solution no longer works. Using the `FUN` argument specification fixes this though: `sapply(x, FUN = function(pkgs) library(pkgs, character.only = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for example:

```
 lapply(X = c("ggplot2", "gtable", "grid"), library,character.only =T)
```

see `?library`

> package, help  the name of a package, given as a name or literal
>   character string, or a character string, depending on whether
>   character.only is FALSE (default) or TRUE).

So here the when you try for example:

```
lapply(X = c("ggplot2", "gtable", "grid"), FUN = function(x) library(x))
## Error: there is no package called 'x'
```

you get an error because `library`  get x as an argument and try to loa the package of name = 'x'